# Ask for 0 or 2 positional arguments with argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm learning argparse module and I want to ask 0 or 2 files.

```
parser.add_argument("infile", nargs = {0,2}, type=argparse.FileType('r'))
```

It should work with :

```
python prog.py
python prog.py infile1 infile2
```

But not with :

```
python prog.py infile1
python prog.py infile1 infile2 infile3
```

Actually I use 2 different arguments with "nargs='?' and I test

```
sys.argv == 1 or sys.argv == 3
```

Comment: Did you mean that you test `sys.argc == 1 or sys.argc == 3`? `sys.argv` is a list is is never going to `==` an integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wanted this once, and found that `argparse` doesn't support it natively, so I wrote it like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse as ap

parser = ap.ArgumentParser(usage='%(prog)s [-h] [a b]\n')
parser.add_argument('ab', 
                    nargs='*', 
                    help='specify 2 or 0 items', 
                    default=['a', 'b'])

args = parser.parse_args()
if len(args.ab) != 2:
    parser.error('expected 2 arguments')

print(args.ab)
```

Note over-riding the usage message when you create the parser, because the default usage message will be misleading otherwise.

Comment: There's a proposed patch in http://bugs.python.org/issue11354 where `nargs` could be (almost) anything that `re` accepts regarding the number of arguments.  In that useage `{0,2}` means the range, not the 2 end points.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same use case, and wim's answer works. Here is the documentation for `usage` in the Python argparse docs in case anyone needs it. This will customize the output of the help message.

[Python Argparse Documentation - Usage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#usage)